# UPDATE query - multiple criteria for same field in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am new to scripting in MS Access and would like to do multiple queries in one instance. I need this query to UPDATE records based off the SET criteria. Below is what I have so far.

```
UPDATE Inspections SET Inspections.Surveyed_By = "TDG/DT"
WHERE Inspections.Surveyed_By="TDG/DavidT";
OR
UPDATE Inspections SET Inspections.Surveyed_By = "TDG/RW"
WHERE Inspections.Surveyed_By="TDG/RobbieW"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
UPDATE Inspections 
SET Surveyed_By = IIF(Surveyed_By = 'TDG/DavidT', 'TDG/DT', 'TDG/RW')
WHERE Surveyed_By IN ('TDG/DavidT', 'TDG/RobbieW');
```

Comment: that works! what If I have three criteria,etc? would I add another "Surveyed_By" on each of the Set and Where clauses? @GMB –

Comment: In that case you would modify the `WHERE` clause by expanding the list of values for `IN`. In the `SELECT` clause, you would use `SWITCH()` instead of `IIF()`, since it is more convenient to handle multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Switch`

```
UPDATE Inspections 
SET Surveyed_By = Switch(
        Surveyed_By = "TDG/DavidT", "TDG/DT",
        Surveyed_By = "TDG/RobbieW" , "TDG/RW" );
WHERE 
    Surveyed_By = "TDG/DavidT"
    OR Surveyed_By = "TDG/RobbieW"
```

Comment: that works! what If I have three criteria,etc? would I add another "Surveyed_By" on each of the Set and Where clauses? @serkanarslan

Comment: Yes, you have to add switch and where part.